# Testing tool to test file download using REST webservice

Tags: java

I need to test csv file download using REST webservice Jersey(JAX-RS) in java
when the url is called using the tool postman. But File is not downloaded in postman. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Postman offers a way to generate curl command. Please generale curl command, run it with `-v` (verbose) option and paste here both the curl command and what it generated.

Comment: I have learnt today about [xy problems](http://xyproblem.info/) and this certainly looks like one. What is the problem you are trying to solve ?

Answer (score 2):

Not enough detail in the question.

According to Postman docs (https://www.getpostman.com/docs/responses):
"If your API endpoint returns an image, Postman will detect and render it automatically. For binary response types, you should select “Send and download” which will let you save the response to your hard disk. You can then view it using the appropriate viewer. This gives you the flexibility to test audio files, PDFs, zip files or anything that the API throws at you."

So it should be doable, but you're probably doing something wrong.

If you don't want to use Postman, you can just copy the URL that triggers the download and then use it in any test script you want, written in any language. For example, Python + requests library.

Comment: I try to do it using POST. Because I'm sending raw data (json data) through API endpoint. And, in service I get the data from mysql db, convert it as csv using CsvBeanWriter and return as StreamingOutput. When I use GET, the csv file is downloaded in browser (but not in postman). How to check using POST.

Comment: Is it possible to do with @POST instead of @GET? Really I don't know whether I'm asking correct or not. But I need to do it with POST method. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a problem as you have "Save Response" button:

[image: PostMan Save Response]

If you mean "Load Testing", you can consider other tools like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/concept.html) or [Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)

Comment: "Save Response" button in not available in my postman

Comment: I need to export as csv file when the url is called. In service, I returned StreamingOutput. It is working when the url is called in web browser. But not working in postman.